# ts-node programmatic usage with require('ts-node/register')

Tags: node.js, typescript

[`ts-node` suggests](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#programmatic-usage) to use `require('ts-node/register')`. And this can be seen in `angular2-webpack-starter` [Protractor configuration](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#programmatic-usage).

What is `require('ts-node/register')` supposed to do? Does it patch `require` to transpile TS files, so a part of Node.js application could be written in TypeScript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does what you think it does. `require('ts-node/register')` is actually the same as:

```
require('./').register({
    lazy: true
})
```

See examples here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/tree/master/register

The `.register` function registers the Typescript compiler for files with `.ts` and `.tsx` extension for compilation on the fly.

Comment: So JS file that does that works like an entry point for TS application that was launched with `node` command and not `ts-node`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, the JS file that does that makes sure that TypeScript files are compiled on the fly and after that step are handled the same way js files do, Maybe to not force the usage ts-node instead of node.

Comment: This sounds exactly like a thing I need. Thanks.

Comment: The link is dead